# Is there joomla Jhtml method for input?

Tags: joomla

So I've tried to use echo JHtml::_('input.text', name, value, attribs, label); for generating input, but I got error message JHtml::text not found.. Is there a way to generate input with text type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, there isn't.

But you could write your class or just use JLayouts to do the job until Joomla gets some sort of real GUI toolkit.